# Yii2 how to add clause where > 0 to the relational attribute

Tags: php, yii2

I have two models: Users, Posts. User has many posts.

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Posts::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I need to get only those users who have posts (posts>0).
How do I write query?

```
Users:find()->where(['>', 'posts', 0])->all()
```

The code above doesn't work.

Comment: can u provide table name and fields

Comment: Table names: users, posts.

Comment: Fields: users.id, posts.user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This query :

```
Users:find()
->where('id IN (select user_id FROM posts GROUP BY user_id)')
->all();
```

Comment: it works, thanks. if I need users who have posts more than 1 or 2? What clause should i add?

Comment: This is subquery if you want user more than two post you need to use leftjoin in it you need having clause

Answer (score 1):

To get users with at least one post you need to use [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp):

```
Users::find()
    ->innerJoinWith('posts', false)
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->all();
```

It should be more efficient that subquery.

---

If you want to filter by number of posts, you should add [`HAVING`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause with count condition:

```
Users::find()
    ->innerJoinWith('posts', false)
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->having(new \yii\db\Expression('COUNT(*) > :posts_nr', ['posts_nr' => 2]))
    ->all();
```

But such queries may be really heavy on large databases - you should consider adding additional column with posts count to users table.

Answer (score -1):

```
$orders = Users::find()->with('posts')->all();
```

Inner join should remove users where posts are null